# Collections.sort

Tags: android

Collections.sort(apps, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(manager));
This is a sort function.The first parameter is an array to be sorted.
Why we need the second parameter?What can the second parameter do?

Comment: You should accept some answers before asking further questions!

Answer (score 3):

[Sort](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) the second argument is [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) so you can provide custom function for comparing the object.

> Collections.sort(apps, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(manager));

It's seems this uses a comparator that compares objects by display name.

Comment: The array apps Contains names and icons.So I puzzle why we need the second parameter?

Comment: @zhen01.wang: No, the "array apps" does not "contains names and icons". `apps` is a `List<ResolveInfo>`. If not, your code will not compile.

Comment: @CommonsWare: No, DisplayNameComparator can be static inner class of ResolveInfo so you can't tell what is the template.

Answer (score 0):

`apps` is a list of `ResolveInfo` objects. `ResolveInfo` isn't `Comparable`, meaning that because it doesn't implement `Comparable` interface, there is no "rule" on how to compare two `ResolveInfo` objects. `sort(List<T> list)` method requires objects in the list to be comparable:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)
```

`DisplayNameComparator` defines logic on how to compare `ResolveInfo` objects by the display names of apps they represent.

Source code:

```
  public static class DisplayNameComparator
        implements Comparator<ResolveInfo> {
    public DisplayNameComparator(PackageManager pm) {
        mPM = pm;
        mCollator.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
    }

    public final int compare(ResolveInfo a, ResolveInfo b) {
        CharSequence  sa = a.loadLabel(mPM);
        if (sa == null) sa = a.activityInfo.name;
        CharSequence  sb = b.loadLabel(mPM);
        if (sb == null) sb = b.activityInfo.name;

        return mCollator.compare(sa.toString(), sb.toString());
    }

    private final Collator   mCollator = Collator.getInstance();
    private PackageManager   mPM;
}
```